# How do I set up DNS with nic.io to point to an AWS EC2 server?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, domain-name, amazon-route53

I purchased a domain one week ago via nic.io. I have elected to provide my own DNS [because they provided no other option].

I'm trying to point my .io domain at my EC2 server instance. I've allocated an elastic IP and associated it with the instance. I can SSH into the instance and access point 80 via the IP address just fine. The IP is 54.235.201.241.

nic.io support said the following: "You have selected to provide your own DNS and therefore if there is an issue with the set-up of the name servers you will need to contact your DNS provider."

So, I created a Hosted Zone via Route 53 in AWS. This created NS and SOA records. I then set the Primary and Secondary servers at nic.io's domain admin page to the SOA record domains. Additionally, I set the optional servers to the NS domains. I did this two days ago, and I can't access the server via the domain.

I ran a DNS check here...still not sure what I need to do: http://mydnscheck.com/?domain=chadjohnson.io&ns1=&ns2=&ns3=&ns4=&ns5=&ns6=.

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That link gives you a few problems to work on:

**cross T+0.51s WARNING: No address records returned for chadjohnson.io. Users who type http://chadjohnson.io/ into their web browser may not see your website**

You need to create an A record in route 53 pointing chadjohnson.io to 54.235.201.241.

**cross T+0.53s WARNING: No address records returned for www.chadjohnson.io. Users who type http://www.chadjohnson.io/ into their web browser may not see your website**

You need to create an A record in route 53 pointing www.chadjohnson.io to 54.235.201.241.

**information   T+0.53s Performing email checks
cross   T+0.54s WARNING: no MX records returned for CHADJOHNSON.IO**

You need to create an MX record in route 53 pointing MX to chadjohnson.io, choose priority 10.

**cross T+0.54s Diagnosis completed with errors**

After you do these steps, you should be able to:

ssh chadjohnson.io and connect to your ec2 node.

Enter http://chadjohnson.io into a browser and connect to your website.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that once you create a hosted zone, you can then create record sets within that hosted zone. Personally, I think the Route 53 user interface could be better.

Comment: The interface is terrible but then again so are all of the DNS web UI's.

Answer (score 2):

> I then set the Primary and Secondary servers at nic.io's domain admin page to the SOA record domains. Additionally, I set the optional servers to the NS domains

ok, so looks like you did this right

> $ dig chadjohnson.io ns +short
>   ns-1031.awsdns-00.org.
>   ns-2014.awsdns-59.co.uk.
>   ns-780.awsdns-33.net.
>   ns-187.awsdns-23.com.

so now just log into route53, and add the missing A record (to be the same as your server IP), and you're good...

missing A record:

> $ dig chadjohnson.io a +short
>   $ dig www.chadjohnson.io a +short
>   $

Comment: Thanks. I'd mark this as the answer, but someone got to it before you :) I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a domain through a separate hosting service, the domain may not support http protocol so you will have to specify the IP address to your hosting service by something called registering glue. It is your ns records' addresses linked to the exact IP address. I recently used showIP Firefox addon to get two of the IP addresses and the latter two failed to load so I used the top google IP's. My site is finally trying to load. Make sure to create a record set an alias record set for your www. I also may be creating a terrible loop but that will get you to something you can play with.